# video players with js API and iPhones

Tags: ios, youtube-javascript-api, vimeo-api

I would like video start to play when use clicks on the specific element on my site. I tested [vimeo player](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) and [youtube video player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo) It works great on the desktop, but when I tested on the iPhone it doesn't.

I know that Apple doesn't allow autoplay. From Apple documentation "Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."

My question is when user click on some html element on the site - can it be considered as initiation of playback by user? How did you solve such problems on the iPhones?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently clicking on an element should allow initiation of a Vimeo video in iOS, but according to a staff member on the Vimeo forums, a mystery bug is preventing this from working.

From https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:107150

> On iOS, playback can only be initiated from a user action. When
>   calling play with the API, somewhere along the line that user action
>   is lost, and triggering the actual video to play doesn't work. We've
>   tried to find a way around it, but so far nothing we've tried has
>   worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this restriction is imposed from Apple side further  answer
[Please see the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498203/3340968)